Sending recorded audio data using XMLHttpRequest only works once
I'm building a sentence recognizer in javascript / python. The process is simple:

First use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia to get a media stream
Then, I use the MediaRecorder alongside with a small library called hark to automatically stop the recording when the user stops talking
Finally I send everything in the .ogg format as a form data to the server.

Here is the code:
let recorder;
let stream;
let hk;
let chunks = [];

function recoverAudio(cks) {
    const blob = new Blob(cks, {type: "audio/ogg"});
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.set("audio", blob);
    http.open("POST", "/api/recognize");
    http.onreadystatechange = () => {
    };
    http.send(fd);

    chunks = [];
}

function record(e) {
    chunks.push(e.data);

    console.log(e);
}

window.addEventListener("load", async () => {
    let el = document.querySelector(".footer-main-button");

    [stream, recorder] = await prepareRecorder();
    recorder.ondataavailable = record;

    hk = hark(stream);
    hk.on("stopped_speaking", () => {
        console.log("stopped speaking");
        el.style.removeProperty("color")
        setTimeout(() => {
            hk.suspend();
            recorder.stop();
            recoverAudio(chunks);
        }, 1000);  // Wait for the last chunk to be recorded
    });
    el.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (recorder.state !== "recording") {
            recorder.start(1000);
            hk.resume();
            el.style.color = "red";
        }
    });
}, true);

On the server side (with flask), i read the file as so:
@app.route("/api/recognize", methods=["POST"])
def recognize():
    audio = flask.request.files["audio"]
    if not audio:
        return flask.abort(400)
    audio.save("./resources/temp/audio.ogg")

But while the first time I record something, everything works fine, as soon as I rerecord something, the file ./resources/temp/audio.ogg is empty. I've checked the DevTools Network, the request contains the valid audio. Even weirder, if I reload the window the code works fine again the first time but not after.
Any ideas why?
(As a reference here is the github containing the whole project: https://github.com/atzitz-amos/TM)

I made your code works ok as follows:
let recorder;
let stream;
let hk;
let chunks = [];

function recoverAudio(cks) {
    const blob = new Blob(cks, {type: "audio/ogg"});
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.set("audio", blob);
    http.open("POST", "/api/recognize");
    http.onreadystatechange = () => {
    };
    http.send(fd);

    chunks = []; // EVEN WITH THIS AFTER FIRST RECORDING THERE IS 1 Blob WHEN START THE ENXT RECORDING (REMOVE THIS LINE OF CODE)
}

function record(e) {
    chunks.push(e.data);

    console.log(e);
}

window.addEventListener("load", async () => {
    let el = document.querySelector(".footer-main-button");

    [stream, recorder] = await prepareRecorder();
    recorder.ondataavailable = record;

    hk = hark(stream);
    hk.on("stopped_speaking", () => {
        console.log("stopped speaking");
        el.style.removeProperty("color")
        setTimeout(() => {
            hk.suspend();
            recorder.stop();
            recoverAudio(chunks);
        }, 1000);  // Wait for the last chunk to be recorded
    });
    el.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (recorder.state !== "recording") {
            console.log(`chunks.length before recorder.start: ${chunks.length}`) // <== Second time ==> chunks.length before recorder.start: 1
            chunks = []; // RESET chunks HERE // <== THIS MADE FOLLOWING RECORDS WORKS OK
            recorder.start(1000);
            hk.resume();
            el.style.color = "red";
        }
    });
}, true);

